# Detecting Circles and Ellipses from Point Arrays in Java

Tags: java, math, computer-vision, ellipse, pattern-recognition

I'm working on a program that processes arrays of coordinate points, with the goal of determining whether these points form geometric shapes such as circles, ellipses, arcs, straight lines, or polylines. If the points form a circle or an ellipse, the program needs to return the parameters of these shapes.

I've looked into two potential methods for this problem:

1. Hough Transform: I understand that it's a feature extraction technique used to detect shapes, but I'm concerned about its computational complexity, especially for detecting ellipses due to the high dimensionality of the parameter space.
2. Direct Least Squares Fitting of Ellipses: This seems to be a straightforward approach for ellipse detection , but I'm concerned that it has the potential to detect polylines as ellipses.

I am looking for advice on:

- Which method would be more suitable for accurately and efficiently detecting circles and ellipses in my scenario?
- How can these methods be adapted to handle the detection of straight lines or polylines, or to differentiate between these and circular/elliptical shapes?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem. Thank you in advance!